# How to run two different node version simultaneously using nvm-windows?

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

Issue: We need to run and use two different node versions i.e 14, 12 simultaneously on two different applications to support the use of `npm run dev`, `npm install` commands with defined version accordingly.
Steps we have tried so far:

1. Created `.nvmrc` file on each application defining the version. This will allow nvm to use the version defined on file i.e `nvm use && npm run dev`.
2. Tried with `nvm exec` command on git bash window.

However, the nvm-windows don't support the exec command and the `.nvmrc` file (https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/issues/169). Is there any way to run two different versions of the node simultaneously?

OS: Windows

Answer (score 1):

You can find the binary path to the `npm` and `node` when you are on specific node version, by typing:

```
which node
which npm
```

and then run the node from its binary path like so (in my pc):

```
/home/sina/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.3/bin/node index.js #first project
/home/sina/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.3/bin/node index.js #second project
```

Comment: How can i run `npm run dev` along with the node version  binary path?

Comment: just change the packa.json and point node bin to the correct bin address you can also set an alias so others on the team can use that. let's say alias node14='PATH 14'  and etc. and inside package.json => dev: "node14 run dev"

Comment: Hi I am trying to configure running different node versions for different microservice repos I have in windows 10. I have angular6 repo which runs on 10.24.1 which I am not able upgrade. rest of the microservices repo can be upgraded to 14+ version. can you suggest how I should configure path to set it for different repos. nvm path : C:\Users\PUSINGH\AppData\Roaming\nvm with folders in it 10.24.1, 12.22.12 and so diff nodes v. with node.exe in root folder of each v. will defining user path in environment variables take only one path always.the npm path is C:\Users\PUSINGH\AppData\Roaming\npm

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bit late on answering this question, but I came across the issue and thought I'll update it with something I found!

For context, I needed to run different node versions across different terminals on windows, and found that nvm-windows does not support it because of the way it works as per Gabriel's answer on top.

Found this wonderful work on github - https://github.com/davfive/nvm-session and all credits to the creator, for building a simple workaround for this. The steps to get this working are clearly explained in the README of the repository, and helped me solve my problem!

However, I believe it requires you to use git-bash/any such bash-supported terminals on windows to get this working!

Answer (score 0):

#### As of March 2024 `NVM` still doesn't support this, but [Volta](https://github.com/volta-cli/volta) does.

Kritarth's answer about the `nvm-session` CLI tool led me to Volta. `nvm-session` has been abandoned in favor of Volta, which also supports multiple Node versions working simultaneously on Windows.