# Set different node version in different folders

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, configuration, nvm

I am dealing with two sibling folder and i need to use two different `node` versions `12.22.11` and `18.14.0` i tried with `nvm use` but everytime i change it in one directory the other one also changes 
OS: Windows 10 
NVM: 1.1.10

Steps:

- in the firstfolder:

1. `nvm use 18.14.0` -> Now using node 18.14.0 (64-bit)

- in the second folder

2. `node -v` -> v18.14.0
3. `nvm use 12.22.11` -> Now using node v12.22.11 (64-bit)

- back on the first folder

4. `node -v` -> v12.22.11

Comment: Folders and directories don't change the environment. Put a `.nvmrc` file in the root of each directory whose content is the version you wish to use, and then type `nvm use` when you switch

Comment: Nvm use is not working in windows it says `A version argument is required but missing.`

Comment: in linux I added an alias to .bashrc to that I could switch between server/app and then use nvm as well

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71108867/how-to-run-two-different-node-version-simultaneously-using-nvm-windows